# Excel : get a cell's value in cell custom format

Tags: excel, format, currency

My problem is simple, but I can't seem to find a solution :

In my Excel sheet, I have many money cells, and I just want to change the currency symbol displayed, "dynamically".

What I would like to do is set a cell with the currency symbol and get the value of this cell in a custom format.

[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: You can do this in a sub or convert the numeric value to text but you cannot dynamically change the cell number format mask with a function. A CF rule would work but you would require one for each currency symbol.

Comment: *I just want to change the currency symbol displayed, "dynamically".* - what defines which currency symbol to display?

Comment: I would put the currency in a cell, and use this cell as a reference

Comment: @Jeeped yes, I'd prefer to skip this option

Comment: because you want to skip that option does not make it untrue.  This can be done in three ways as @Jeeped stated; 1. vba, 2. changing the number to text in a different cell through the TEXT() function `TEXT(A1,"[$" & B1 & "-809]#,##0.00"` or 3. Use a separate Conditional Format rule for each currency symbol desired.  There is no way that I know of that will allow you to create a Custom Number Format that references another cell.

Comment: @ScottCraner thank you, I just wanted to make sure there was no other way to do it. For the first method using VBA, anyone who will open the file, no matter the excel version, will see the good currency ? Or should they "apply" the VBA code ? I've never used VBA